# Catching error client side with JSON payload using Next.js and custom server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, next.js

I'm using Next.js with a custom server (Express) and coming across an issue with basic api error handling.

I have some simple error handling middleware which looks similar to this:

```
app.use((err, req, res) => {
    res.status(400).send(message);
});
```

If `message` is a string I'm able to catch the error client-side (when using fetch and promises). However if I use something like:

```
res.status(400).send({ message });
```

This does not get caught but I can access the payload within the `then` handler of the promise. How can I send an error response with a json payload that can be caught in the `catch` handler?

Comment: Can you add your client-side code? I was having a similar problem where I forgot to use "await" for JSON response, e.g. `const msg = await res.json()`

Answer (score 0):

you can send response in JSON format by changing

```
res.status(400).send({ message });
```

to

```
res.status(400).JSON({ error:message });
```

Comment: I still have the same issue whether I use send or json.

Comment: which library are you using for client side axios or fetch

Comment: Native Fetch function.